# Valid to run post-hoc tests on matched data or running afoul of Table 2 Fallacy?

Tags: difference-in-difference, post-hoc, matching, pre-post-comparison

After completing a difference-in-differences matched cohort analysis to estimate the pre/post treatment effect of a home health nursing intervention compared to a control group, my employers are interested in dissecting the matched data.

In particular, do we achieve different treatment effects looking at subsets of the original matched data (e.g., high vs. low risk scores, 0 vs. 1+ ER visits in the baseline time period)?

Is this a valid form of analysis or are we getting into trouble with the [Table 2 Fallacy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6103824/#:%7E:text=A%20%E2%80%9CTable%202%20Fallacy%2C%E2%80%9D,together%20in%20a%20single%20table.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Table 2 fallacy refers to when one interprets effect estimates of confounders in a regression table as-if they were the variable of interest all along. So no, the analysis you've described does not run afoul of this fallacy. That being said, you would need to be careful of multiple-test correction, and you would need to be aware that the data will very likely *not* be matched any more, so you should have a plan in place for how to model potential confounders.

Comment: I understand the Table 2 Fallacy in the linked paper refers to multiple regression. However matching is another way to condition on confounding variables that are causally linked to the exposure or treatment and the outcome ($Y_{post}$ - $Y_{pre}$ in my analysis). Can't we extend the fallacy to matching as well?

Comment: I see what you mean. I think if you naively treated groups (i.e., risk scores) as if they were matched too, then I think you would be running afoul of it. I assume that you'll be including the appropriate covariates when testing the interaction between treatment and group? In that case, I don't think it does.

Comment: My worry is we're treating former confounders X like high/low risk or 0/1+ ER visits as the "new" exposure variable. In which case we'll have multiple causal paths: X -> Y and X -> A -> Y where the exposure A now becomes a mediator. Or there could be other variables confounded with X and Y, but not A and Y, that should be conditioned on if we want to estimate X -> Y. Unless I'm wrong I think you'd have to rerun the matching algorithm with X as the new exposure.

Comment: It sounds like you have access to more data than what you used in the initial analysis? In that case, I would agree that the best approach is to go back to the full data set and start there. Is there any reason not to just do regressions testing interactions between "exposure" and treatment in the full data set?

Comment: Yes you're right - it's ok to run outcome models on matched data as long as it's well balanced, there are plenty of examples in literature and online. The Table 2 fallacy still exists with regression models as you stated.